# How to get closest total of paper money from a determined price and amount of paper

Tags: python

So based on the price of product the user can only pay with the determined amount of paper money, so for example the price is `17000` and the amount of paper allowed is `1`
if in the currency the allowed paper amount are `[100000, 50000, 20000, 10000, 5000, 2000, 1000]` the paper money with the closest amount is `[20000]`
another example is if the price is `23000` and the allowed paper is 4 then the paper money with the closest amount is `[20000,1000,1000,1000]`, the price can only be between `100000` and `1000`
So i how do i implement this in python ?

i have only tried to get the amount of paper allowed from a price

```
price = int(input('input price : '))
paper_money = [100000, 50000, 20000, 10000, 5000, 2000, 1000]
change = price
for paper in paper_money:
    if change < paper:
        continue
    total_paper = int(change / paper)
    change = change - ( paper * total_paper )
    print('paper {} : {}'.format(paper, total_paper))
```

the input:

1. the price for the product = `17000`
2. the amount of paper allowed = `2`

the currency is already determined as variable `[100000, 50000, 20000, 10000, 5000, 2000, 1000]`

the output:

1. an array with the length of the amount of paper allowed and if adds up is equal or closest to the price = `[10000,10000]`

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: This sounds very similar to the knapsack problem. I suggest googling "knapsack problem" to get more information and tips on how to solve it.

Comment: well it show me which paper money used how many sheet of it which add up to the price

Comment: Please give a specific example with input and output then explain what the output should be instead and why.

Comment: i've edited my question @Code-Apprentice

Comment: 1. You show what the output should be. Also include what it actually is.

Comment: 2. Where are you using the amount of paper allowed? It seems like you need to add this to the input and yoru algorithm.

Comment: the actual output from my code is actually the amount of paper money which has the value that add up to the price, I know it is supposed to be the input , But I just can't wrap my head around where to put it to get the output that it should be

Comment: To solve problems like this, often it is good to start by figuring out how you would solve it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
price = 23000
allowed = 2
paper_money = [100000, 50000, 20000, 10000, 5000, 2000, 1000]

remaining = price
money = []
for i in range(allowed):
    closest = min(paper_money, key=lambda x:abs(x-remaining))
    money.append(closest)
    remaining = remaining - closest

money
>>> [20000, 2000]
```

Comment: It looks like it does not work. I tested with price = 28000 and I got [20000, 10000]. If price = 24500, I have [20000, 5000]

Comment: What should the answer be according to you?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad... I expected for instance [20000, 5000, 2000] in the first case, a value *under* the total, but it's the opposite

Comment: Btw, why `range(2)`? IS it related to `allowed` variable?

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer.

Comment: What should the output be for `price = 21001` and `allowed = 2`?

Comment: The question says "closest", so `[20000,1000]`